# Issue with basic CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a project for a course in coursera. I was instructed to make a simple layout for a website. I was instructed to use a `<header>, <main>` and a `<footer>`. I was supposed to have an image in my  and have text over the image. I placed the image in a `<section>` and used position absolute to have my content over the image. Afterwards, my next `<section>` would go onto the right side of my first  rather than underneath. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```css
        main {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .banner {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .banner img {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #info {
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 800px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 430px;
            left: 250px;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.594);
        }

        h1 {
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        p {
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <section class="banner">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/14/09/45/diamond-1199183_1280.jpg" height="556px">
            <div id="info">
                <h1>MANGATA GALLO</h1>
                <p">Mariana is the owner and the lead designer of Mangata and Gallo. After graduating from design school
                    with a specialization in diamond cutting and metal smithing, Mariana opened a store in her hometown,
                    Austin and started to grow her business online. Mariana has always managed every aspect of the
                    business, from jewelry design to marketing to e-commerce. However, she recently hired several
                    artisans to help craft her designs and a young employee to help manage the company website and
                    social media accounts.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="cards">
            <article class="product">
                <h3 class="card-title">Wedding rings</h3>
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTirprNMUJgd2fFMXWpwgs4GRao7zGDsQSfeA&usqp=CAU"
                    alt="">
                <p class="card-description">Temporary Text</p>
            </article>
        </section>
    </main>`


</body>
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, it looks like some of the text was cut off? Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake you've made is [see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVTZI.png), you have put an extra (") this.

second mistake is you have putted an position absolute without defining the main container as position relative.

here is the right code->

```
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}
.banner {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: reletive;
}

.banner img {
  width: 100%;
}

#info {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.594);
}

h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

The html is ->

```
<main>
  <section class="banner">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/14/09/45/diamond-1199183_1280.jpg" height="556px">
    <div id="info">
      <h1>MANGATA GALLO</h1>
      <p>Mariana is the owner and the lead designer of Mangata and Gallo. After graduating from design school with a specialization in diamond cutting and metal smithing, Mariana opened a store in her hometown, Austin and started to grow her business online. Mariana has always managed every aspect of the business, from jewelry design to marketing to e-commerce. However, she recently hired several artisans to help craft her designs and a young employee to help manage the company website and social media accounts.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="cards">
    <article class="product">
      <h3 class="card-title">Wedding rings</h3>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTirprNMUJgd2fFMXWpwgs4GRao7zGDsQSfeA&usqp=CAU" alt="">
      <p class="card-description">Temporary Text</p>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: I did not se the mistake on the <p>. Thank you for pointing that out. However, I used your code and was still unable to achieve getting my next <section> under my first <section>

Comment: describe the problem visually, or more detailed way, I did not understand what u want to do. if you want another section under the first section then wrap the two section with a div and assigned it position relative, and the  two section inside the div, assigned it position absolute and use the z-index to make the section you want in top .